# Solving the functional equation $f\big(xf(y)-y\big)+f(xy-x)+f(x+y)=2xy$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

The problem says that:

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the set of real numbers. Find all functions
> $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the condition:
> $$f\big(xf(y)-y\big)+f(xy-x)+f(x+y)=2xy$$
> for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

I am a little bit lost in the solution, I started to search some special values.

If $(x,y)=(0,0)$:
$$\begin{align} f\big(0f(0)-0\big)+f(0)+f(0)=0 \\ 3f(0)=0 \end{align}$$
Thus: $f(0)=0$.

Is it right to continue and find some values by substitution or there is another technique?

Because I found that if $y=0$:
$$f\big(xf(0)\big)+f(-x)+f(x)=0$$
therefore:
$$\fbox{$f(x)=-f(-x)$}\tag1\label1$$
If $y=1$:
$$f\big(xf(1)-1\big)+f(0)+f(x)=2$$
Giving $0$ to $x$:
$$f(-1)=2$$
Using \eqref{1} we have:
$$\begin{align} f(-1)&=-f(1) \\ f(1)&=-2 \end{align}$$
With all these values I conclude that:
$$f : x \mapsto -2x$$
I feel that I'm wrong and I need another technique to solve this. But the condition is satisfied:
Since $f(x)=-2x$ thus:
$$\begin{align} f\big(xf(y)-y\big)&=-2\big(x\cdot (-2y)-y\big) \\ &=-2y+4xy\end{align}$$
and:
$$f(xy-x)=-2xy+2x$$
Also:
$$f(x+y)=-2x-2y$$
Thus:
$$\begin{align}f\big(xf(y)-y\big)+f(xy-x)+f(x+y)&=2y+4xy-2xy+2x-2x-2y \\ &=2xy \end{align}$$
Nevertheless, I feel that there's another function, and this technique is wrong. Please help me, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your working (IE substituting in specific values) is fine up to the last step. How can you conclude that $f(x) = -2x$ just from 3 values? E.g. why couldn't the function be $ f(x) = - 2x + \sin {\pi x}$?

Comment: I knew it. That's what I am asking about sir, but when I did a substitution  i had the same value $2xy$

Comment: So what you've now shown is that "$f(x) = -2x$ satisfies the functional equation". Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: When you set $y=1$ you made an error in the substitution. What you should get is $f(xf(1)-1)+f(0)+f(x+1)=2x$. Thus, if you then set $x=0$ you get nothing new, just that $f(-1)+f(1)=0$ which you already knew.

Comment: A solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1533379p9235417

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $P(x,y)$ be the assertion
$$f\big(xf(y)-y\big)+f(xy-x)+f(x+y)=2xy\text.$$

$P(0,0)$ gives $f(0)=0$.

$P(x, 0)$: $f(-y)+f(y)=0$ therefore $f$ is odd.

$P(-x, -y)$ gives
$$f\big(xf(y)+y\big)+f(xy+x)-f(x+y)=2xy\text.\tag{*}\label{*}$$

By plugging $x=1$ in \eqref{*}, we get $f\big(f(y)+y\big)=2y$, hence, $f$ is surjective.

$\therefore \exists a: f(a)=-1$.

$P(x,a)$: $f(-x-a)+f\big(x(a-1)\big)+f(x+a)=f\big(x(a-1)\big)=2ax$ (note that $f$ is odd).

$\therefore f\big(x(a-1)\big)=2ax$.

if $a=1$, $f(0)=2x$ which does not make sense.
so $a\ne 1$, which implies that $f$ is linear. Putting back to the given assertion, we get $f(x)=x$.

Comment: There is also the option $f(x) = -2x$